# Using triggers to add new user to a mailing list

Tags: 7, actions

I would like the Mailman Integration module to add any new user to a mailing list. I enabled Triggers and created an action in PHP. I then assigned the action to execute when a new user is created. I can not figure out how to get the $user object for this new user though. I can get the object of myself, the logged in user using global $user, but how do I get the new user?

```
$user = [newly added user];
$mail = $user->mail;
$name = $user->name;
$uid = $user->uid;
$list_name = 'list';
mailman_integration_subscribe($list_name, $mail);
mailman_integration_set_user_option($list_name, $mail, 'fullname', $name);
mailman_integration_insert_users($list_name, $mail, 0, $uid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Actions and Triggers, I just made a custom module:

```
function mailman_user_subscribe_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category){
  $uid = $edit['uid'];
  $name = $edit['name'];
  $mail = $edit['mail'];
  $list_name = 'list';
  mailman_integration_subscribe($list_name, $mail);
  mailman_integration_set_user_option($list_name, $mail, 'fullname', $name);
  mailman_integration_insert_users($list_name, $mail, 0, $uid);
}
```

It's possible that a custom "After adding user" PHP action does nothing more than place the code within a hook_user_insert function. If so, I could have replaced all my object calls to $user with array calls to $edit.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about how you've configured your environment but have you looked into this module? It appears to extend the rules a little bit.

https://www.drupal.org/project/user_mailman_register